# Jquery divs with certain class

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to know If divs with certain class contain at least an element ?

```
<div id="l1col1" class="selects1" style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"></div>
<div id="l1col2" class="selects1" style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"></div>
<div id="l1col3" class="selects1" style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><select><option selected>1</option></select></div>
```

In the example above i want to be able to tell if any of the divs contains a select Or Not
Is this possible ?

Comment: `$('.selects1').find('select').length > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) selector:

```
var $notEmptyDIVs = $('div.selects1').filter(':not(:empty)');
```

And for empty ones:

```
var $emptyDIVs = $('div.selects1').filter(':empty');
```

Comment: This works in this exact situation, but it does not give what the TS whats, a way to tell if there's a `select` in `div`

Comment: @Martijn This answer this: "Is there any way to know If divs with certain class contain at least an element ?"

Comment: It does, but Pete already gave me the same answer, in a comment though, so i will accept yours. Thanks

Comment: "It does, but Pete already gave me the same answer, in a comment though" Where? Cannot see it. And "Doesn't it answer question???" comment was because of a downvote now removed ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff   $('.selects1').find('select').length > 0 –  Pete 11 mins ago  :)

Comment: @user2515601 ya but that's not exactly the same. Pete's one check for SELECT, here it's checking for any element. Now it is depending what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$("div.selects1:has(select)")
```

To check if there is any just do

```
$("div.selects1:has(select)").length > 0
```

Or, you can use the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) *method* instead, for possibly increased performance.

```
$("div.selects1").has("select")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length`:

```
$('.selects1').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().length) {
        // Your code for .selects1 that has children
    }
});
```

or you can use **[has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**:

```
$("div.selects1:has(select)")
```

Comment: Can't i do it without looping through each DIV ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Following

```
$('.selects1').each(function() 
{
    if($(this).children().length > 0) 
    {
    //Your code 
    }
```

});

Here Check if the number of children are greater Than 0